# speed of 'this' keyword in js

Tags: javascript, this

I ran a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/testy123) test to check the speed of `this` vs a normal variable. I was shocked to see `this` perform so slowly. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your benchmark is broken.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/testy123

Comment: I have tested that and I too find out that cached references are faster than referring to a self field. If I find my test I will comment here.

Comment: @gloo what is the `this` value when executing a function in JavaScript? Try `var gg=function(){ console.log(this); }` followed by `gg()` what is `this` ? :)

Comment: Okay I will try. Is the link working now?

Comment: Not my test, but similar http://jsperf.com/this-vs-cached

Comment: okay I see. need to make it a method as in obj.gg().

Comment: The test has been updated. Thanks for the help. `this` was refering to  the window object.

Comment: Your test is biased. 'this' is not meant to be used that way : http://jsperf.com/testy123/4 shows that perf of 'this' is around 30% slower, so nothing to be much worried about given jsperf's accuracy.